# Procedure in MSSQL is not inserting values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have two databases in MSSQL and by a program inserting values into first table and i want this procedure to insert the same values into second table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ylk_banka_ekle]
   @banka_kod varchar(25)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MikroDB_V15_TEST2.dbo.BANKALAR
                     (ban_RECid_DBCno, ban_RECid_RECno, ban_SpecRECNo, 
ban_iptal, ban_fileid, ban_hidden, ban_kilitli, ban_degisti, ban_CheckSum, 
ban_create_user, ban_create_date, ban_lastup_user, ban_lastup_date, 
                     ban_special1, ban_special2, ban_special3, ban_kod)

SELECT 
                     ban_RECid_DBCno, ban_RECid_RECno, ban_SpecRECNo, 
ban_iptal, ban_fileid, ban_hidden, ban_kilitli, ban_degisti, ban_CheckSum, 
ban_create_user, ban_create_date, ban_lastup_user, ban_lastup_date, 
                     ban_special1, ban_special2, ban_special3, ban_kod
FROM BANKALAR
WHERE (ban_kod = @banka_kod)

UPDATE BANKALAR SET ban_RECid_RECno = ban_RECno WHERE ban_RECno != 
ban_RECid_RECno

END

GO
```

In sql when i execute this procedure it says only 'Command is successful' but not adding any rows into second database.
Anybody can give an idea where my mistake is?

Comment: It cannot add rows because it is an UPDATE statement.

Comment: there is only one insert statement in your code that is why only one db gets an insert

Comment: I have two databases in MSSQL and by a program inserting values into first table and i want this procedure to insert the same values into second table.

Comment: What datatype is ban_kod of BANKALAR table?

Comment: What is the name of second table?

Comment: Databases have different names but both have same tables and columns. Datatype is nvarchar.

Comment: Run your insert query. Is it working ? If yes, then run your update statement. Is it working ? That's how you proceed. :)

Comment: If i run insert or select or update with manually given value for ban_kod like ban_kod = 'BNK1', all parts are working fine. I can insert ,retrieve or update. But ban_kod = @banka_kod is not working as i understood.

Comment: @SerterALP Ideally, `EXEC ylk_banka_ekle BNK1` should do. If its not, maybe your other program is not returning BNK1 ?